# Using ANTLR4 to find all methods in a Java project

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to write a short program that can extract all methods from a Java project (I have the source files).

After doing a little bit of research I came to realize that doing so using regular expressions is a bad idea, since Java is a context-free language and since it will be problematic to correctly match all the curly braces. The next step was to find an alternative way, and I learned that using the ANTLR parser would be the best idea. I found many examples (some older than the others) but I was unable to find an example for how to extract all the methods in a project (including their body).

Can anyone write a short example, so I can know how I should get started?

Comment: you can scan files and use this pattern to catch all functions declarations if it helps  ([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*\([^((.*))]*\)\s*{

Answer (score 1):

You can easily just use the parse tree and a listener to trigger a call to your code. Have you looked at the [doc](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/listeners.md)? It has essentially your exact solution.

Comment: I read the docs, I couldn't get from "overriding the listener methods" to actually understanding what code should I write

Comment: Create a new class that extends from the generated Listener (JavaListener here) and override the `visitMethodDeclaration(..)` method which prints out the method with signature. You can follow the doc mentioned above and do this for each java source file.

Comment: The doc link is not accessible.

Comment: Doc moved to github awhile back. Updated link.